# Zoom the view of TEdgeBrowser

Tags: delphi, webview, microsoft-edge, tedgebrowser

What is the equivalent of the piece of code below for zooming with the new `TEdgeBrowser` delphi component?
This is how I used the old `TWebBrowser` component.

```
procedure ApplyZoom(ZoomValue: Integer);
var
  pvaIn, pvaOut: OLEVariant;
begin
  pvaIn := ZoomValue;
  pvaOut := Null;

  WebBrowser.ControlInterface.ExecWB($0000003F, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, pvaIn, pvaOut);
end;
```

Comment: What is the actual value of `ZoomValue`? I usually change `TEdgeBrowser.ZoomFactor` property.

Comment: It was expressed as a percentage, the default was 100 (%). But I see that with zoomfactor it works differently but that's what I need. Thank you